# Gradient not flowing after application of @tf.custom_gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing **Lei et al. (2015)'s Rationalizing Neural Predictions** neural network to generate extractive summaries for **NLP** problems.

The architecture requires a sampling layer which selects a subset of the available words from a text input. As sampling is NOT differentiable, I use **@tf.custom_gradient**, assigning an **'artificial'** gradient of 0 to the sampling layer.

The problem is that the layers above the sampling one do not train anymore (it looks like all the gradient flow further down the network is essentially nullified).

My question is how can I circumvent this effect and make the network ignore or skip the non-differentiable layer?

I have tried a hard sigmoid activation (e.g. `alpha = 60`) to approximate selection between 0 and 1, but it is not good enough (let alone elegant).

## This is the layer with custom gradient

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def sampling(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return x*0+0
    dist = tfd.Bernoulli(probs=x,dtype = tf.float32)  
    return dist.sample(),grad
```

So, this is what happens:

1. Neural Network layer 1  # Does not train
2. Neural Network layer 2  # Does not train
3. The layer with custom gradient # Not supposed to train
4. Next layer # Trains well
5. Next layer # Trains well
6. Next layer # Trains well
7. Output

So how do I make 1) and 2) still train?

Comment: If you make the gradient 0 at one point, then all the previous gradients will become zero as well. If you want to avoid a layer from training, you could specify that on the optimizer. For example, you can just pass `trainable=False` when you create the variable so it's not among the variables optimized by default. Or you can pass a `var_list` to [`tf.train.Optimizer.minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#minimize), or `compute_gradients`, clip the gradient values and then `apply_gradients`...

Comment: Hi Jdehesa, thank upu very much for your answer! Do you think that if I switch the 'trainable' parameter off for the problematic 3rd layer (i.e. the non-differentiable one) the gradient would 'flow' over it? Cheers, Kiril

Comment: Yes, the only thing `trainable=False` does is excluding that variable from the collection of trainable variables (you can see the contents of that collection with `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)`). It does not affect how gradients flow. I'm not sure how exactly this maps to TensorFlow 2.x though, since it [deprecates collections](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180905-deprecate-collections.md).

Comment: If I set the 'trainable' parameter to False (still using the overridden gradient = 0), as you said the upstream layers do not train.  However, I tried another thing: I forked the input to the sampling layer and made it both feed in the sampling layer as well as bypass it and merge with later layers. So now the upstream layers train too! Thank you very much!

Comment: You should not use the overridden gradient, making it zero is what nullifies the upstream gradients. However, I am realizing that the problem is that there is no gradient for the sample of a Bernoulli distribution (that is, TensorFlow does not define a gradient for it, and I cannot think of a sensible way of defining it). This means, there is no analytic measure of how the output changes when something in the initial layers changes. Without this, there can be no training for those variables (you cannot tell how they should be updated).

Comment: Thank you very much, jdehesa

Comment: I now realise that what this model actually does is application of an attention mechanism to sequences of words. So 'hard' attention cannot be differentiable and only a 'soft' version would work.